# Fix Dates in Pyspark DataFrame - set to minimum value

Tags: pyspark, data-cleaning

I have a data frame with a timestamp field - RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED:timestamp
For some reason, there are dates that are less than 1900-01-01.  I don't want these, what I want to do, is for every value in the column of the dataframe where the RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED<'1900-01-01 00:00:00' then set the timestamp to either 1900-01-01 or null.
I've tried a few ways to do this, but it seems some more simple must exist. I thought something like this might work, but

```
import datetime
def testdate(date_value):
    oldest = datetime.datetime.strptime('1900-01-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d')
    try:
        if (date_value < oldest):
            return oldest
        else:
            return date_value
    except ValueError:
        return oldest
udf_testdate = udf(lambda x:testdate(x),TimestampType())
bdf = olddf.withColumn("RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED",udf_testdate(col("RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional evaluation using [`when and otherwise`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html) to set `RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED` to either `null` or `1900-01-01 00:00:00` whenerver the value is `< '1900-01-01 00:00:00'`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [("1000-01-01 00:00:00",), 
        ("1899-12-31 23:59:59",),
        ("1900-01-01 00:00:00",), 
        ("1901-01-01 00:00:00",)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED",))\
          .withColumn("RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED", F.to_timestamp(F.col("RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED")))


# Fill null

df.withColumn("RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED", 
              F.when(F.col("RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED") < "1900-01-01 00:00:00", F.lit(None))
               .otherwise(F.col("RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED")))\
  .show(200, False)

# Fill default value

df.withColumn("RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED", 
              F.when(F.col("RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED") < "1900-01-01 00:00:00", F.lit("1900-01-01 00:00:00").cast("timestamp"))
               .otherwise(F.col("RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED")))\
  .show(200, False)
```

### Output

**Fill `null`**

```
+--------------------+
|RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED|
+--------------------+
|null                |
|null                |
|1900-01-01 00:00:00 |
|1901-01-01 00:00:00 |
+--------------------+
```

**Fill `1900-01-01 00:00:00`**

```
+--------------------+
|RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED|
+--------------------+
|1900-01-01 00:00:00 |
|1900-01-01 00:00:00 |
|1900-01-01 00:00:00 |
|1901-01-01 00:00:00 |
+--------------------+
```

Comment: yeah. thank you.  I'm not sure how or why this works, so I google it some more but thank you.